# Find and replace text in files with xonsh

Tags: xonsh

How would one replace text in all files within a given directory (recursively) while in the xonsh shell?

For example, how would I rewrite the below bash command:

```
find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try this:

```
for fpath in pg`*baz*`:
    if not fpath.is_file():
        continue
    fpath.write_text(fpath.read_text().replace('foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, the recursive case is pg`**/*baz*`

As for backticks, see https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#advanced-path-search-with-backticks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the quotes to tell xonsh that `{}` and `+` are the arguments:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' '{}' '+'
```

The complete example of testing your command in xonsh:

```sh
echo 'foo foo' > some_baz_file
find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' '{}' '+'
cat some_baz_file
# bar bar
```

Another way is to use the xonsh [macro command](https://xon.sh/tutorial_macros.html) and just run bash line as is:

```
bash -c! find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

To simplify this approach there is [xontrib-sh](https://github.com/anki-code/xontrib-sh) extension that allows just add the `!`  sign before the command:

```
! find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```